# Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens - error 400

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

i get 400 error when i exchange auth code for access token & refresh token

### gcp oauth 2 creds setup

- webapp
- redirect `https://kii*****jie.chromiumapp.org`
- clientID `423*****5p1.apps.googleusercontent.com`
- secret `ciA*****JGA`

### code

I get my auth code via

```
//js
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth' + 
              '?client_id=' + clientId + 
              '&response_type=code' + //id_token
              '&access_type=offline' + 
              '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri + 
              '&scope=' + scopes + 
              '&include_granted_scopes=true'
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({'url': url, 'interactive':true},
       function(url) {
           //authcode in url
       }
```

given `authCode = 4/3AGw0c***70ishchar***7G7LdY`

then i try to get exchange auth code for access token & refresh token

```
//let url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" i've also tried this url
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }
      const requestBody = {
        code: authCode,
        redirect_uri: 'https://kii*****jie.chromiumapp.org',
        client_id: '423*****5p1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        client_secret: 'ciA*****JGA',
        grant_type: "authorization_code"
      }

      const response = await axios.post(url, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)

// qs.stringify(requestBody) = `code=4%2FAGw0c***70ishchar***7G7LdY&
// redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fkii*****jie.chromiumapp.org&
// client_id=423*****opf0pvrr5p1.apps.googleusercontent.com&
// client_secret=ciA*****JGA&
// grant_type=authorization_code`
```

but i get `Error: Request failed with status code 400`

#### links

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2
- https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

Answer (score 1):

400 status means there's probably something wrong with your HTTP request.

Should it be your ID without the `apps.googleusercontent.com` part?

```
const requestBody = {
        code: authCode,
        redirect_uri: 'https://kii*****jie.chromiumapp.org',
        client_id: '423*****5p1', # CHANGED
        client_secret: 'ciA*****JGA',
        grant_type: "authorization_code"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok fixed it.

client id cannot have ".apps.googleusercontent.com"